java.lang.SecurityException: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
after updating my android app in sdk 34 app showing
java.lang.SecurityException:  One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:5202)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleCreateService(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2650)
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'me.hiennguyen.circleseekbar:circleseekbar:1.0.1'
implementation 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.11'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'

}

According to the developer's documentation:
Apps and services that target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher and use context-registered receivers are required to specify a flag to indicate whether or not the receiver should be exported to all other apps on the device: either RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED, respectively. This requirement helps protect apps from security vulnerabilities by leveraging the features for these receivers introduced in Android 13.
for more details:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#runtime-receivers-exported
Code sample:
Context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
            // or 
registerReceiver(receiver, filter, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);

